# How to automate creation of tuples of template classes based on elements of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, tuples, metaprogramming

I have an `std::array` that is filled with all the types of an enumeration. I'd like to implement my tuples based
on this.

```
class CompBase
{
public:
    enum CompType{
        INPUT,
        GRAPHICS
        // ( + 5-10 additional types)
    };

    static const std::array<CompType, 2> compTypeArr;
};

const std::array<CompBase::CompType, 2> CompBase::compTypeArr =
{
    CompBase::INPUT,
    CompBase::GRAPHICS
};

template<CompBase::CompType compType_e>
class CompHolder {}; // owns one component

template<CompBase::CompType compType_e>
class CompContainer {}; // references N components

class CompInterface
{
    // ...
private:
    std::tuple // I want to automate this,
    <
        CompHolder<CompBase::INPUT>,
        CompHolder<CompBase::GRAPHICS>
    > compHolders;
};

class CompHandler
{
    // ...
private:
    std::tuple // and this process, based on the predefined array
    <
        CompCont<CompBase::INPUT>,
        CompCont<CompBase::GRAPHICS>
    > compContainers;
};
```

To my understanding `std::make_tuple` is not even `constexpr` before `c++14` [ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple)
so I'm not sure if this is possible at all since I'd need a `c++11` method. The presence of the array is I think sort of mandatory because an enumeration alone doesn't provide the necessary functionality for something like this.

Comment: what about replacing you enum by a type list? then would be really easier to use later. IMHO, having enum to list 'types' is quite poor, variadic templates are here for that.

Comment: It might be poor, but I get rather nice functionality with it and it's easier to implement; although yes I'm running into a few problems. I've used variadic templates before and I actually don't think they would make things cleaner than this, or as extendable (if it works on the other hand I'm very open to it of course) .

Comment: Since you don't seem to mind having to write the list of enumerators twice (it's the third copy you want to automate here), then you could keep the `enum` and replace the `array` with an instantiation of a variadic template, from which you can get the automation you want. Does this sound like a solution?

Comment: Otherwise, the problem is not with `make_tuple`, but with `array`: its const accessors were only made `constexpr` in C++14, so in C++11 you can't get those array elements and use them to build a type - they won't be accepted as non-type template arguments.

Comment: @bogdan Oh I see. I'll look into that method, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that works in C++11. As discussed in the comments, using an `std::array` would work in C++14, where its const accessors were made `constexpr`.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

class CompBase
{
public:
   enum CompType {
      INPUT,
      GRAPHICS
      // ( + 5-10 additional types)
   };
};

template<CompBase::CompType...> struct CTLHelper;
using CompTypeList = CTLHelper<
   CompBase::INPUT,
   CompBase::GRAPHICS
>;

template<template<CompBase::CompType> class, class> struct CompTupleMaker;
template<template<CompBase::CompType> class H, CompBase::CompType... Es> 
struct CompTupleMaker<H, CTLHelper<Es...>>
{
   using type = std::tuple<H<Es>...>;
};

template<CompBase::CompType compType_e>
class CompHolder {}; // owns one component

template<CompBase::CompType compType_e>
class CompContainer {}; // references N components

using CompHolderTuple = CompTupleMaker<CompHolder, CompTypeList>::type;
using CompContainerTuple = CompTupleMaker<CompContainer, CompTypeList>::type;

class CompInterface
{
   // ...
private:
   CompHolderTuple compHolders;
};

class CompHandler
{
   // ...
private:
   CompContainerTuple compContainers;
};


int main()
{
   // just a quick check
   std::cout << std::is_same<CompHolderTuple, std::tuple<CompHolder<CompBase::INPUT>, CompHolder<CompBase::GRAPHICS>>>::value << '\n';
}
```

If you really need those enumerators in an array in C++11, you could use a built-in array declared `constexpr` - you can reference its elements in constant expressions. I'd say that only makes sense if you need the array for something else as well; if all you need is a holder for the list of enumerators, the variadic solution is simpler in this case. For the array solution, you'd need something similar to C++14's [`std::index_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) to expand the array.

Comment: Can I ask, did you declare `CompTupleMaker` with a second template argument of type to invoke a compiler warning if a `non-CompType` parameter is passed, or is there other reason to it?

Comment: @AromaticCodeProducer The second parameter of `CompTupleMaker` is meant to be the type that holds the list of `CompType` enumerators (in the template arguments used to create it). We need that list passed in as a parameter pack, in order to have something to expand when building the `tuple` specialization. The partial specialization of `CompTupleMaker`solves that problem. It does indeed also ensure that we get a compiler error if anything else than a specialization of `CTLHelper` is passed in, since that will try to instantiate the primary template, which is not defined.

Comment: @AromaticCodeProducer (The primary template could be defined with a body containing a `static_assert`, in order to provide a nicer compile-time error message in that case.) Anyway, I'm not sure if this answers your question. If not, let me know and we can discuss it further.

Comment: I see, there's much more potential in partial specialization than what I thought before, very interesting.